# How to render super size texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics

I use the API `glGetIntegerv` to gain the maximum size of viewport and texture. Both of them return 16K x 16K pixels.

Here is the codes:

```
GLint maxTexture,maxViewport;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTexture);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS, &maxViewport);
```

However I need a larger size of texture to show a series of images of high resolution. I tried to set the viewport size to 32K x 32K，and the program runs successfully. It seems that the maximum of viewport size I got from the API glGetIntegerv is not quite right.

But I can't set the texture size to a value larger than 16K x 16K.
Maybe I should try to create more than one texture unit and each of them has the size of 16K x 16K.

Someone presents a application called Manual Whole Slide Imaging.
here is the hyperlink:

http://www.microvisioneer.com/

It seems that the super size texture has realized in this application. 
So is OpenGL the right tool to resolve my problem or is there any other solution?

UPDATE：Just now I found that when I set the viewport to 32K x 32K and no error occurred,but its true size is still 16K x 16K.

Comment: What do you mean by "1024*16*1024*16" size? The queries you use give a value for *width* (and *height* for viewport) You can look for values returned by cards [here](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_stats_caps_single.php?listreportsbycap=GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) The values ARE enough for the max display size of the installed hardware.

Comment: As @Ripi2 mentioned. What you are talking is about viewport and it has nothing to do textures. Textures will have max size based on hardware and you can  render any size to any size viewport.

Comment: glViewport silently clamps to the supported range according to spec. This is not an error.

Comment: Dependning on the content of the textures you could up the bit depth and internally treat it as multiple sets of bit planes, e.g. if your original textures are RGBA8 you can load 4 of them into a RGBA32 (if supported) and split it in a shader.

Comment: I've used [`libtr`](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/bp/TR.html) in the past to generate high-resolution screenshots.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Why don't you downsize the image or arrange an M x N grid of smaller images?

Comment: @genpfault HI！Can TR render a texture larger than the max size which is depeneded on gpu?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your advice! However I don't understand what you mean.Can you show me a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a RGBA8 type. In C it looks like this:

```
uint8_t rgba[4] = {0x00, 0x44, 0x66, 0xff};
```

But you could represent it also with:

```
uint32_t rgba = 0x004466ff;
```

Similarly for type RGBA32:

```
uint32_t rgba[4] = {0x00000000, 0x44000000, 0x66000000, 0xff000000};
// or
uint128_t _rgba = 0x000000004400000066000000ff000000; // assuming there is a uint128_t...
```

HOWEVER you are allowed to treat those bits any way you want. You could:

```
uint128_t rgba[4] = {tex1rgba, tex2rgba, tex3rgba, tex4rgba};
```

In above example you have put tex1 rgba8 data in the red channel of the
opengl internal rgba32 texture, tex2 in the green channel and so on. Assuming the textures are edge-by-edge in real life in a 2x2 manner a texcoord (0.1,0.1) would map the rgba8 value in the red channel at texcoord 2*(0.1, 0.1). Texcoord (0.6, 0.7) map to the rgba8 in the alpha channel at 2*(0.6-0.5, 0.7-0.5), assuming the texture in the alpha channel is located diagonally to the texture in the red channel.

I´ve used this technique myself in the opposite direction for making my application support 16-bit luminance (L16 or R16) on platforms only supporting 8-bit channels. Essentially I loaded a 16-bit single channel texture into a 8-bit dual channel texture, and split it in the shader as high/low-word.

Notice you can´t use any texture filtering such as GL_LINEAR while doing this. You have to filter yourself. In my experience this is not a very big problem in practice.